# Augmented Dataset not visible in the app under the 'Dataset' list

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am just starting to work with Einstein Analytics. Need help with one issue that I am facing.

I created an app and then created a dataset inside it from Salesforce objects. This dataset is combining data from 2 objects. The name of my dataset is 'Sales Order with Items'. I did all the necessary steps and ran the dataflow.

My dataflow ran fine and saw that it augmented the 2 objects and registered the new dataset with no errors, but when I go and check the app, I do not see my newly created dataset under the 'Dataset' lists. What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

are you able to see the dataset in Data Manager? If so then you don't have App permissions, else when you are not able to see the Dataset in Data manager then your dataset didn't get created.